# Adding controls to a Panel inside a for loop only adds the first iteration of control

Tags: c#, loops, controls

I'm trying to dynamically create a list of panels containing a label and a textbox and put those panels into a bigger panel.

My problem is that only the first child panel gets added to the parent panel. 
I've tried adding the panels directly into controls as well as this addrange method.

Also I'm aware of another question with this problem but it is six years old and the solution did not work for me.

the Panel pnl is being populated by a Panel containing a label and textbox that is already on the form. that panel is then deleted from the controls and pnl  remains

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:
The code will loop multiple times but when it reaches `panel1.Controls.AddRange(controls);` the total count of panel1.controls is 1 regardless of the length of array controls

```
Panel pnl;
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control[] controls = new Control[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(ddlPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString()); i++)
        {
            pnl.Name = "pnl " + i.ToString();
            if (i!= 0)
                pnl.Location = new Point(pnl.Location.X, controls[i - 1].Location.Y + Height);
            pnl.Show();
            controls[i] = pnl;
        }
        panel1.Controls.AddRange(controls);
    }
```

Comment: Code like this makes me suspicious: `int.Parse(ddlPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString())`. Tell us what `ddlPlayers.SelectedItem` is but NOT what `ddlPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString()` is.

Comment: @DourHighArch The ddlPlayers is a dropdown of numbers 2-8. so Selected Item is going to be a number between 2 and 8

Comment: Have you tried to initialize pnl inside for loop?

Comment: pnl = new Panel(); then panel1.Controls.Add(pnl);

Comment: @Luthfay yes I have tried that

Comment: What makes you think “Selected Item is going to be a number between 2 and 8”? If `ddlPlayers` is a `System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.ComboBox` then `SelectedItem` is type `Object`, not an integer. Use your debugger. Set a breakpoint on `ddlPlayers.SelectedItem` and tell us what actually is, not what you think it should be and not what `ToString` shows. Is this ASP.NET? WinForms? UWP?  Something you're not telling us is going wrong and we can't help until you tell us what is going on.

Comment: @DourHighArch ddlPlayers shows up in my debugger as 6 because i selected the value 6 from my list. I would ask that you go back and read the edit I made for clarification as it states that this was never a problem because the for loop loops as it should.

Comment: @DourHighArch This project is in winforms

Comment: You don't create any new panels so you have only one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't declaring a new panel, I was just using the same control. I thought by putting the controls into an array it meant they would be different but I was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

check this line ---> `int.Parse(ddlPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString())`

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: @Mr.feel can you elaborate?

Comment: Code like this makes me suspicious: int.Parse(ddlPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString()). Tell us what ddlPlayers.SelectedItem is but NOT what ddlPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString() is. – Dour High Arch 8 mins ago

Comment: You need to check the value of "ddl Players.SelectedItem" during debugging.

Comment: @Mr.feel That line has no effect on the rest of the code. it loops through multiple times. When the code gets down to "panel1.controls.addrange(controls);"  regardless of how many controls are in the array, only one control is added to the parent panel